# Python Class, Operator Overloading

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-class

Recently while getting my hands on with Python Class concepts, I came upon this observation and was not able to understand.

When I try and create instance out of the below class interactively(Python console), I also get the `Finding __len__` line in output.

```
class MyClass(object):
    counter = 0
    data = 'Class Variable'

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.value = -1

    def __str__(self):
        return "Instance {} is the {} instance".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.counter)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(f'Finding {item}')
        return self.__dict__.get(item, f'Attr {item} not available, {self.__dict__}')

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        print(f'Deleting attr: {item}')
        if item in self.__dict__:
            del self.__dict__[item]
        else:
            print(f'Cannot find {item} in {self.__dict__}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = MyClass()
    print(inst.id)
```

But running it as a top level module, doesn't add this additional line in output.

Can someone help me understand, why `Finding __len__` output would be displayed interactively.

Below is an interactive output,

```
import WS1
x = WS1.MyClass()
Finding __len__
x.name = 'Yathin'
Finding __len__
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Doesn't happen when I run it nor creating an object in shell

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes even I didn't see this behavior within cmd nor in  Python shell.
I found this with PyCharm 2020.1 (Community Edition)

Comment: Didn't happen in Pycharm also, in both ways (Pycharm 2018.3.3)